# Alternatives for null in relations

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have these tables:

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        product                          |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| product_id  | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| name        | varchar(255) |                            |
| type        | enum         |                            |
| vendor_id   | int(11)      | FOREIGN KEY                |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        voucher                          |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| code        | varchar(255) | PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY    |
| product_id  | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY    |
| order_id    | int(11)      | FOREIGN KEY NULLABLE       |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        order                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| order_id    | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| user_id     | int(11)      | FOREIGN KEY                |
| product_id  | int(11)      | FOREIGN KEY                |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

I have pre-generated vouchers in **voucher** table, and *NULL* for order_id, until it was purchased. **voucher** is like a sub type for **product**. Is there any alternatives for *NULL* in relation (order_id)? And maybe there is better approach in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a NULL value in the foreign key column, you will have to add a special “no order” entry in the `order` table.

That solution would work just as well as using NULL values, and perhaps it would make your queries simpler.

One possible downside might be that you cannot define the foreign key as `ON DELETE SET NULL` any more.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `voucher.order_id` is a foreign key, any alternative would need to have an entry in order. NULL seems like a reasonable solution to me.